# Visual issue with css3 animation and jquery (hover flip card)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Read me: -->** Im having troubles when I hover the flip card, if you move the cursor while hovering inside the div is triggering continuously and it makes an annoying effect, so here is what I need:
**1)** I want to hover the flip card and dont trigger animation again even you move the cursor inside while hovering.
**2)** I also need center p tag vertically in the flip card, `margin-top` is working and `margin:auto` is not working, I put the 2 examples in the snippet, check next classes:

```
.card .front p {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.card .back p {
    margin: auto;
}
```

So why is not working `margin:auto`? I wont use margin-top, need the content at the center. Here is the working snippet code:

> **Updated question:**
>   I also need achieve the next: one time you hover the flip card the animation must be completed, even you hover out the div, and then flip to the original position again, I tried next but it doesnt work:

```
$(".container").hover(function(){
            $(this).find(".card").toggleClass('flipped')
        }, function(){
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                $(this).find(".card").toggleClass('flipped')
            }, 1000);
    });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".card").hover(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('flipped')
        }, function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('flipped')
    });
})
```

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 260px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto 40px;
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    -moz-perspective: 800px;
    -o-perspective: 800px;
    perspective: 800px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#main{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
button{
    width: 30%;
    height: 10%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    cursor: default;
}

.card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
    -moz-transform-origin: right center;
    -o-transform-origin: right center;
    transform-origin: right center;
}

.card.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
    -o-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
    transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
}

.card div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.card .front {
    background: red;
}
.card .front p {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.card .back p {
    margin: auto;
}

.card .back {
    background: blue;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
    transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="main"><br>
        <section class="container">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="front"><p>Test</p></div>
                <div class="back">
                    <p>MyBack</p> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that because you are transforming the element that has got the hover, the pointer may get out of the box, causing an unwanted change of state from `hover` to `none` and back again.

You could catch the `hover` event on the `main` div. To align the elements, the simplest way is to use [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). `margin: auto` will not work since it sets `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to `0` by default.

Here are the changes I've made :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").hover(function() {
    $(".card").toggleClass('flipped')
  }, function() {
    $(".card").toggleClass('flipped')
  });
})

.card .back {
  /*no changes*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card .front {
  /*no changes*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

And a working example :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").hover(function() {
    $(".card").toggleClass('flipped')
  }, function() {
    $(".card").toggleClass('flipped')
  });
})
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
  perspective: 800px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#main {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button {
  width: 30%;
  height: 10%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  cursor: default;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: right center;
}

.card.flipped {
  transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
}

.card div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card .front {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card .back p {
  margin: auto;
}

.card .back {
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="main"><br>
    <section class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
          <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
          <p>MyBack</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

How about it ?

Comment: Thats nice about the hover, but why isnt work margin auto to center the element?

Comment: margin: auto will not work since it sets margin-top and margin-bottom to 0 by default.

Comment: Thanks for answer, last question, could you please check my updated question?

Comment: We should conitnue this discussion in chat : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158959/room-for-visual-issue-with-css3-animation-and-jquery-hover-flip-card